# How can I resolve an Arithmetic Overflow Error when inserting data from a CSV into a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-2.7, csv, pyodbc

I am trying to read in a `.CSV` file of test results into my SQL Server Express database, and I am able to get two of the 25 rows into my database, but then it errors out with the following error:

> DataError: ('22003', u'[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type
>   numeric. (8115) (SQLExecDirectW); [22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)')

It doesn't specify which field or column is causing the issue; and I have searched Google and Stack Exchange, but haven't found anything to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Python 2.7, SQL Server Express, and pyodbc for the connection between the two.

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

print
print("Please wait while I connect to database...")
print

# Connecting to the Database
mydb = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-5I015MM\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

# Turning on autocommit
mydb.autocommit = True

# Creating a cursor object
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("USE mydatabase")

print
print("Connection to the database was successful!")

# Adding Test Results to database - Look into this...
strSQL='''INSERT INTO TestResults(datasource, modelNumber, testSequence, reportingCondition, testDate, isc, voc, imp, vmp, ff, pmp, noct) 
VALUES ('SolarLabs',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''

#open csv file
with open('test_results_NOCT.csv','rb') as f:
    csvfile= csv.reader(f)
    next(csvfile)

    for row in csvfile:
        mycursor.execute(strSQL, row)

print
print("Test Results added successfully")
print
```

And here is the CSV code that I am trying to read into SQL:

```
Model,Test Sequence,Condition,Date,Isc,Voc,Imp,Vmp,FF,Pmp,NOCT
KUT0012,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.2,44.7,4.88,35.7,75,174.3,51.9
KUT0003,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.34,44.7,5.03,35.7,75.2,179.7,52.1
KUT0003,TC200,STC,5/7/2008,5.2,45.1,4.83,36.4,75.2,176.2,-
KUT0004,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.21,44.8,4.91,36.1,76,177.2,51.8
KUT0004,TC200,STC,5/7/2008,5.17,45.1,4.81,36.5,75.3,175.6,-
KUT0004,Hotspot,STC,6/25/2008,5.09,45.6,4.7,37,74.9,173.7,-
KUT0001,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.32,44.6,4.95,35.4,73.8,175.2,51.8
KUT0001,TC200,STC,5/7/2008,5.2,45,4.77,36.8,75.1,175.6,-
KUT0006,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.35,44.4,4.95,35.8,74.5,177.2,52
KUT0006,UV,STC,6/5/2008,5.28,44.6,4.84,35.8,73.7,173.7,-
KUT0006,TC50,STC,7/4/2008,5.22,45,4.72,36.9,74.1,173.9,-
KUT0006,HF10,STC,8/1/2008,5.21,45.1,4.69,37,73.9,173.4,-
KUT0006,Termination,STC,8/19/2008,5.23,45,4.62,37.3,73.2,172.5,-
KUT0007,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.25,44.4,4.87,35.8,74.6,174.2,52.1
KUT0007,UV,STC,6/5/2008,5.39,43.9,4.84,35.5,72.5,171.7,-
KUT0007,TC50,STC,7/4/2008,5.56,44.7,4.87,36.8,72.2,179.3,-
KUT0007,HF10,STC,8/1/2008,5.5,44.6,4.85,36.4,72.2,176.8,-
KUT0005,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.13,44.3,4.84,35.6,75.7,172.3,51.7
KUT0005,Damp Heat,STC,5/8/2008,5.11,45.5,4.7,37.4,75.4,175.6,-
KUT0005,Static Load,STC,5/29/2008,4.95,45.6,4.67,37.6,77.6,175.5,-
KUT0008,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.13,44.6,4.84,36,76.2,174.4,52.2
KUT0008,Damp Heat,STC,5/8/2008,5.17,44.9,4.78,36.2,74.4,172.7,-
KUT0008,Hail,STC,5/21/2008,5.14,44.5,4.73,35.8,74,169.4,-
KUT0011,Baseline,STC,3/11/2008,5.24,44.7,4.99,35.8,76.1,178.4,51.9
KUT0011,Outdoor Exposure,STC,4/17/2008,5.05,44.3,4.79,35.6,76.4,170.7,-
```

And here is the table schema:

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbEqy.jpg)

Comment: Please post the schema of your table so we know data types of columns. Try: `exec sp_columns YourTableName`.

Comment: @Parfait - Thank you for getting back to me; my apologies for not posting the schema.  I updated my question, and have an image of it down at the bottom of the question.  I tried copying and pasting it to the question, but the formatting made it hard to read.  Let me know if this doesn't work for you.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You may already have noticed, but I think it's because of the '-' in the NOCT.

Comment: @mmukai - Yep!  That was it!  Earlier today, I tried just deleting the '-', but it still gave me the same error.  So, I figured that wasn't it.  But, instead of deleting it, I put a '0' in the field, and it just went through without any more errors.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Interesting that no error or undesired results occurred on your dates. I would think Python run the division `3/11/2008` prior to parameterization since the date value is not quoted. Plus it is not in the ISO format: `'YYYY-MM-DD'` required for date literals.

Comment: @Parfait - Oh, there is plenty of odd things about this whole set up.  Haha!  Perhaps it was converted through the pyodbc module when it went from the CSV to SQL database?  I will fully admit that I am new to all of these functions and operations; but I am definitely learning a lot as I go along.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @owenp, run sql server profiler and see the statements running against sql server. For SQL Server express, there is open source profiler available. Refer to article: https://www.diwebsity.com/2016/04/19/express-profiler/

Comment: @VenkataramanR - Thank you so much the heads up on that program; checking it out right now!